# Jenkins hangs while deploying large files to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, large-files

When our Jenkins project pipelines produce jar files with sizes close to 60 MB or more and try to deploy them to Artifactory, they just hang and never finish.

For smaller jar files - below 10 MB - there is no problem.

We are using Jenkins version 2.414.1 and Artifactory Commercial License version 7.68.7 rev 76807900. Jenkins uses Artifactory Plugin 3.18.9, Maven Integration Plugin 3.23 and JFrog Plugin 1.5.0.

We have configured the Artifactory tomcat like this:

tomcat:
connector:
extraConfig: "maxPostSize='-1' connectionTimeout='1500000'"

There is no logging in Artifactory or Jenkins indicating a problem.

We have searched for similar problems posted on stackoverflow and similar sites, but we haven't found any.

Most developers using this type of setup have had it working without problems for large WAR files. Our applications are based on Spring Boot 3 that produces very large jar files. Could our problem be caused by either Jenkins or Artifactory being confused by the very large jar files?

Comment: Same problem for WAR files

Comment: Do you check the max upload size in artifactory?

Comment: maxPostSize='-1' should remove the limit of upload size. By the way, using JFrog Cli to upload to Artifactory works fine for the large files. But how do I use it in a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

First, you should install JFrog Cli on Jenkins. In the jenkinsfile of your project, you should add:

```
jfrog 'jfrog-cli'
```

to tools. I the deployment stages, you should have the following steps:

```
jf 'rt mvn-config'
jf 'rt mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs  deploy:deploy' // build & deploy artifacts
jf 'rt bp' // publish build info
```

Finally, in your pom.xml, you should add:

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>libs-release-local</id>
            <url>artifactory-server-url/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>libs-snapshot-local</id>
            <url>artifactory-server-url/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Rememeber to add Artifactory credentials for your repository id's in the maven settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

For publishing artifacts to Artifactory with Jenkins, the official plugin is recommended by JFrog. https://plugins.jenkins.io/artifactory/

This plugin is compatible with JCasC (Jenkins Configuration as Code).
Sample configuration after setup :

```yaml
JCasC:
  configScripts:
    artifactory: |-
      unclassified:
        artifactorybuilder:
          useCredentialsPlugin: true
          jfrogInstances:
            - instanceId: <your-instance-id>
              platformUrl: <your-platform-url>
              artifactoryUrl: <your-artifactory-url>
              deployerCredentialsConfig:
                credentialsId: <your-artifactory-credentials>
```

Once configured, the functions provided with the plugin can be used within your declarative pipelines to publish maven artifacts. All available functions can be found here https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/declarative-pipeline-syntax.

Sample :

```html
stage('Publish jars to Artifactory') {
    steps {
            rtMavenRun(
                    pom: "<your-pom-path>",
                    goals: "<your-maven-command>"
                )
            rtPublishBuildInfo(
                    serverId: "<your-instance-id>"
                )
    }
}
```

An important caveat here is the requirement to use "install" in your maven command as opposed to "deploy" for deploying artifacts (Ref : https://devpress.csdn.net/cicd/63179e8f26059229d1c850c0.html).

I have used this setup with 1000s of jars with 500+ MBs and it has worked without any issues.

This configuration also provides feedback and direct links on the build UI which can be used to directly access the required jars from Artifactory